# Can I calculate S3 cost using an API?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I would like to know if there is a way to calculate cost of s3 usage programmatically. I found the aws price list api, but I don't think it is what I am looking for. For eg: Lets say I calculate 1 PB as our usage then I want an API to respond with the cost of 1 PB of standard S3 usage which would be around $32k per month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Price List API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/) provides access to well-structured static files with all possible current offering/region/price combinations... but you'll have to parse and interpret them in your own code.  There is not a query API to provide the calculation service you appear to be asking about.

Comment: Thanks. I am hard coding the price per gb per month in the script for now, since we just need a rough estimate for budgeting, as per the info on this page https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/